# Sum involving hypergeometric function $\mbox{}_1 F_2$

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, summation

Trying to simplify the sum
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z_1^n}{n!} {}_{1}F_{2}(1;a+n,1-a+n;z_2),
$$
where $a\in(0,1)$, $z_1,z_2>0$, and ${}_{1}F_{2}$ denotes the appropriate [version](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/) of the generalized hypergeometric function. The obvious

```
Sum[(Subscript[z, 2])^n/n!*HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {a + n, 1 - a + n},Subscript[z, 1]], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

does not work. Any suggestions? I suspect the result is some kind of a bivariate hypergeometric function, or perhaps a product of two univariate hypergeometric functions.